# Receiving ArrayList from servlet to jsp page

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I want to receive  ArrayList from Servlet to a JSP page.

Here is what i am doing in Servlet

Stored the arraylist in schoolarraylist

```
request.setAttribute("Arraylist", schoolarraylist);
```

In JSP(CreateStudent) i am trying to access arraylist

```
<%ArrayList<SchoolBean> get= ( ArrayList<SchoolBean> )         

<%request.getAttribute("schoolarraylist"); %>
```

What i want to do is load the list of schools from database into a drop down box to be displayed while creating student in this JSP.

This is the code i wrote between the  tag

```
<%for (SchoolBean c : get) {%>

<option value="<%=c.getSchoolname()%>"> <%=c.getSchoolname()%>
</option>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 4):

[setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) stores an object called `name` in the request. So you are storing an object called "Arraylist".

[getAttribute(java.lang.String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) retrieve an object called `name` from the request. So you are trying to retrieve an object called "schoolarraylist".

So, change your code that sets an attribute with the same name as you are using to retrieve it, e.g.:

```
request.setAttribute("schoolarraylist", schoolarraylist);
```

It doesn't matter what you call the attribute but be consistent in the name you use when setting and getting it.

BTW, you should consider using a tag library, such as [JSLT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html). For example, if you have stored your list in the request as an attribute called "schoolarraylist", you could do something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="school" items="${schoolarraylist}">
    <option value="<c:out value='${school.schoolname}'/>"> <c:out value='${school.schoolname}'/>
    </option>
</c:forEach>
```